# Устройства в сети пропадают

Tags: маршрутизация, роутер, маршрутизатор

> R1 - 192.168.1.1 dhcp
>
> R2 - 192.168.1.2 static
>
> pc1(r2) - 192.168.1.5 static

команда из pc1 подключенного от r2

```
sudo arp-scan -I wlp4s0 -l
```

не всегда выдаёт список подключенных устройств. Иногда только

```
Interface: wlp4s0, datalink type: EN10MB (Ethernet)
Starting arp-scan 1.8.1 with 256 hosts (http://www.nta-monitor.com/tools/arp-scan/)
192.168.1.2 10:62:eb:75:3a:46   (Unknown)

1 packets received by filter, 0 packets dropped by kernel
Ending arp-scan 1.8.1: 256 hosts scanned in 1.378 seconds (185.78 hosts/sec). 1 responded
```

R1 и R2 подключены кабелем через свитч. За R2 всё работает нормально, периодически отсутствует пинг между R1 и R2. Однако интернет через него по 3G работает нормально для PC1. Компьютеры подключенные промежуточно через свитч не пингуются из R2 не смотря на то что в настройках стоит статический адрес.

Что не так, и как это можно исправить?
R1 - Sagemcom 2804v2, R2 - dir-825ac

UPD 1:

после перезагрузки роутера ситуация нормализовалась, однако хотелось бы знать первопричину.

UPD 2:

```
sudo arp-scan -I wlp4s0 -l
192.168.1.1 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   SAGEMCOM
192.168.1.3 xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx   CADMUS COMPUTER SYSTEMS
...
ping 192.168.1.3
PING 192.168.1.3 (192.168.1.3) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 192.168.1.3 ping statistics ---
133 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 135166ms
```

при этом 192.168.1.3 пингуется с других машин за R2

Информация о R2:

> Модель:DIR-825ACG1
>
> Аппаратная ревизия:G1A
>
> Версия ПО:3.0.2

[резервная копия dir-825ac](https://cloud.mail.ru/public/D3KA/yPAfdMH7A)